# What does it mean when my variable is always converted to 2147483647......?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following code as my entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="group")
 *
 **/
Class Group {

/**
 *
 * @Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 **/
 private $phone;

(etc...)

__get( $var ) {
return $this->$var;
}
__set( $var, $val ){
 $this->$var = $val;
}
```

I then try to modify this with a number larger than nine digits. for example,

```
$group->phone = 5147811326;
```

$phone is set to `2147483647`. The same occurs with `1111111111` (it is conveted to `2147483647`)

If I try `514781`, it keeps the numbers fine. But over 9 digits it just converts. I originally had the mysql column as an integer but converted it to string...still a problem.

what is happening?!??!!

Comment: I don't know much about doctrine2 but 2147483647 looks like 2^31-1 or signed integer max value.. Its logical that 5147811326 converts to that because its greater. 1111111111 is less than 2147483647 so its odd..

Comment: I don't know wat `doctrine2` is, but I recognise that the number you're getting is 0x7FFFFFFF - you might be running into some kind of numeric overflow.

Comment: I can't think of a problem other than overflow.  You're trying to squeeze more data than can fit into the size of the variable that you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the data type you are using is 32 bits. [2147483647](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647) is equal to 2<sup>31</sup> − 1.

Comment: why 1111111111 converts to that then? it fits into 32 bits.

Comment: Yes I think this is correct. I'm just using a string now and it's working much better. Hours of agony are over! thanks!

Comment: 111111111 ...doctring might be doing something to it when it's converting. Since the ORM sits on top of php I'm sure it uses some kind of memory when converting, might be an error.

Answer (score 2):

The number "5147811326" cannot be stored in a 32-bit integer because there are simply not enough bits. The highest binary value of a 32-bit integer is "11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111" (or 2147483647 in the decimal system). Try eiter a 64-bit integer or a string to store the phone number.